# Recuperar valor de SELECT al editar registro con relación muchos a muchos

Tags: php, laravel

Espero que puedan ayudarme con la siguiente cuestión.

Estoy desarrollando un aplicativo en Laravel 10 y me he quedado atascado al editar un SELECT y tener que recuperar el valor asignado al mismo.

Tengo la siguiente relación de tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los modelos **User** y **Category** he añadido las funciones correspondientes para una relación **Many to Many**.

**Modelo User**

```
public function categories(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Modelo Category**

```
public function users(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

En el controlador, obtengo las categorías registradas y las categorías que dicho usuario tiene asignadas y las paso a la vista:

```
public function edit(User $user) {
    $categories = Category::all();
    $catUser = json_decode(User::find($user->id)->categories);
    return view('admin.users.edit', compact('categories', 'catUser'));
}
```

Por último, en la vista recorro las categorías y compruebo si alguna de ellas pertenece al usuario para marcarla como seleccionada.

```
<x-select name="category" id="category" @class(['border-red-700' => $errors->has('categories')])>
                                <option value="">Indique categoría</option>
                                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                    @foreach ($catUser as $cat)
                                        <option value="{{$category->id}}" @selected($category->id == $cat->id)>{{$category->category_name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endforeach
                            </x-select>
```

Aquí es donde me surge el problema, ya que todos aquellos usuarios que no tienen ninguna categoría asignada, muestran el select vacío.

Os agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Gracias.

Comment: El problema que veo es que solo estas imprimiendo los options de las categorias del User (dentro del foreach anidado). Pero deberias imprimir los options para todas las categorias (dentro del primer foreach pero fuera del foreach anidado) y marcar como `selected` solo aquellas que esten presentes en las categorias del User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para aprovechar los [metodos disponibles](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#available-methods) de las colecciones de Laravel, en el controlador podrías que devolver ambos datos como colecciones, sin hacer ese `json_decode`:

```php
public function edit(User $user) {
    $categories = Category::all();
    $catUser = $user->categories;
    return view('admin.users.edit', compact('categories', 'catUser'));
}
```

Nota que tampoco es necesario volver a consultar el User, pues ya lo tienes en una variable.

Luego en la vista puedes hacer un `foreach` para imprimir un `option` para cada una de las categorías (todas, no solo las del usuario), e ir comprobando si la colección de categorías del User [contiene](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-contains) a la categoría para la que estas imprimiendo el `option` para marcarla como `selected`:

```php
<select name="categories" multiple>
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        @php( $selected = $catUser->contains('id', $category->id) )
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" @if($selected) selected @endif >
            {{ $category->category_name }}
        </option>              
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración. Un saludo.